# Best practice for handling sequential errors in CoreData with Swift 2.0

Tags: swift

Lets say I do something like this:

```
do {
  try context.executeFetchRequest(..)
  // tweak the results
  // build a relation
  try context.save()
} catch { ... }
```

Would it be better to do a second `do` block for the call to `context.save()` or just do all my try calls in line as shown above?

My though is its better to do them as nested `do` blocks if I want to handle any potential errors differently. Similarly, they should be done consecutively if you want to handle any errors the same.

Answer (score 0):

My point is that `fetching`, `relation building` and `saving` - is a whole different things one from each other and, thus, must be performed in different methods, each with it's own apropriate error handling code.

Like (in pseudo code):

```
...
entity = ...
// need to "build some relation" with entity
try {
    call db_update_operation ((context) -> {
        entities = fetch_from_context(context, ... fetch parameters ... )

        connecting = entity.inContext(context)
        for (relationed in entities)
            relationed.entity = connecting
    })
} catch () {
    // dealing with errors, if any
    // can get here within 3 situations:
    //   1. there was error in fetch conditions
    //   2. there was error in relations establishing
    //   3. there was error in context saving
    // each of that must be treated differently, like
    // fetch/save errors should be passed to higher
    // levels of abstraction, while relation-establishment 
    // errors can be processed here
}


func fetch_from_context( context, ... )

    try {
        fetched = context.fetch(..., &error)
    } catch () {
        // dealing with errors
        // only fetch errors should be processed here
    }

end

func db_update_operation( callback )

    context = detauch_context (get_parent_context)

    try {
        callback(context)

        try {
            context.save(&error)
        } catch () {
            // dealing with save (and only save ) errors, if any
        }

    } finally {
        // make sure, that we've relesed created context
        // other errors is not our deal at this point
        ...
    }
end
```